# NSImage doesn't work with all images

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I'm loading images using NSImage class in my application like that.

```
 if let image = NSImage(contentsOfURL: openPanel.URL!) {
  ...
 }
```

It works fine with most of images. I then convert it to CGImage and use like I want. But with some images it simply glitches and I cant understand why. For example If I load image size `2133x2133`, it appears like nothing and if I'm printing `image.size` I see very strange `(511.92, 511.92)`.

What can cause that type of behaviour? All images are in PNG format. At the same time, I can load image with size `(2048.0, 1536.0)` and everything works just fine.

How one should even start debugging loading with NSImage?

This is the example of an image:

http://rgho.st/6CVKMR2ZM/image.png

When I create CGImage from that using this func, I see nothing:

```
    var imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)
    let imageRef = newImage.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us an example image file that doesn't work.

Comment: It's not strange, it's a 2133x2133 image that has an image DPI setting of 300 pixels/inch. (2133/300 = 7.11 inches * 72 pts/inch = 511.92 pts.) ;-). An example image would be helpful. Logging the entire image instance can usually provide a wealth of information, including the type and number of image reps the NSImage contains. (An `NSImage` is simply a container for one or more `NSImageRep`s.)

Comment: @NSGod: sorry for being a bit pedantic :  An `NSImage` is simply a container for **Zero** or more `NSImageRep` s

Comment: On 10.11.4 I'm getting a valid `NSImage` with one `NSBitmapImageRep`, which I can display in an `NSImageView` with no problems. `imageRef` is valid, I can make another `NSImage` from it, and that also displays fine. It looks exactly the same as it does in Preview. How exactly are you displaying the `imageRef` that you created? Since it's a partially transparent image and has a scale, are you perhaps drawing only one of the transparent corners?

Comment: @HeinrichGiesen: true, forgot about that; it will generally have one or more, but not necessarily...

Comment: @KurtRevis my guess was about corner too, but idk how to draw full image, not only 511.92x511.92 part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution: use real image size, not the one Apple calculates for me using DPI.

```
    var w = 0
    var h = 0
    for r in newImage.representations {
        w = max(w, r.pixelsWide)
        h = max(h, r.pixelsHigh)
    }
    var imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(w), CGFloat(h))
    let imageRef = newImage.CGImageForProposedRect(&imageRect, context: nil, hints: nil)
```